# Cloud Armor rule for allowing traffic between API and Application on same load balancer

Tags: google-cloud-armor

I have an Angular application hosted on App Engine and a FastAPI server hosted on Compute Engine both served via a single loadbalancer (separate host URLs, say demo-app.com and demo-api.com respectively). The loadbalancer has a static IP.

Is there a cloud armor rule that will ALLOW traffic only between the application (demo-app.com) and the server(demo-api.com) and DENY all other traffic? Two separate rules for either direction is also fine.

Tried using the loadbalancer IP but I guess that's pointless as the remoteIP in the HTTP request is of the device using the application.
Can't use header values (like 'Host' and 'Referer') as they are not trustworthy.
Is there any way I can use cookies to make this work?

Can't find any detailed documentation on the same, would appreciate if anyone could even just point me at the right reading material.

Comment: You can trust the `host` header. If that header is wrong the SSL negotiation will fail.

Answer (score 0):

you can make it IP or network based like in the example below

```
request.headers.host.matches('demo-app.com') && inIpRange(origin.ip, '127.0.0.0/24')
```

where 127.0.0.0/24 - is the Public IP address **network** where your demo-api.com is hosted

OR

```
request.headers.host.matches('demo-app.com') && '127.0.0.1,127.0.0.2'.contains(origin.ip)
```

where 127.0.0.1,127.0.0.2 - are the **exact Public IP addresses** where your demo-api.com is hosted

- when creating rule, go to Advanced mode
- past one of the above scripts
- by action policy set Allow